# Cancel BufferReader task

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer

I am having navigation drawer in which there are 8 menus in the drawer and each menu is having fragment which is downloading different data so each fragment is having its own AsyncTask. Now the problem is when users selects another menu from navigation drawer while first one is fetching data and populating Adapters of first data, app gives "unfortunately application stopped"... I want to add one more point so that you will get this more clearly. That is when I am opening the app first fragment starts fetching data and populating Adapter. If I do exit from the app while download of data (of first fragment) app do crashes because data is being downloaded and trying to update fragment adapter(of the data) but the fragment has been detached(). So basically I want to stop data download of the first fragment when user selects second one.

Comment: This is a pretty interesting quandary; are you storing your AsyncTasks somewhere where the UI thread has access? You might need to invoke a cancel with a very brief pause when a menu is selected; having a central list of tasks connected with background fetching for each menu item would let you do that in a uniform way.

Comment: So all I have to do is make new fragment and put AsyncTask into it ?

Comment: I am having AsyncTask in the Fragment only

Comment: The point of what I'm saying is that you need to have the set of all `AsyncTask`s accessible from any fragment. Since singletons are nasty and probably shouldn't be used, you should stick it in whatever counts as global-ish scope; in this case, your main activity would probably be preferred.

Comment: In short, *move them so that instead of just being stored in the Fragment, they are stored in a List in your Activity (or a singleton of some sort), and the fragment has a reference back to them*. Then, have a method or something that goes through that list and cancels + removes everything when it's not needed.

Comment: It was the first thing I did but it was not working because through asynctask in MainActivity I can not update adapters of the fragment

Comment: Well, then I don't know. I'm not really an Android expert myself, I wish I could help more.

Comment: You are good helper but may be my destiny bot working

Comment: ...sure thing, dude. Wish I could have helped more.

Comment: Thank you very much keep coding